# Casting new column to an INT after a case statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following SQL query which removes % symbols from a column and changes empty values to NULL

```
SELECT col,
CASE
    WHEN (REPLACE(col, '%', '') = '') THEN NULL
    ELSE REPLACE(col, '%', '')
    END AS newcol
    FROM test;
```

I'm now trying to get this to cast to an INT after this but I am getting Syntax errors, I tried to do so with the following code but I'm receiving syntax errors.

```
SELECT col,
       CASE WHEN (REPLACE(col, '%', '') = '') THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST(REPLACE(col, '%', '') AS INT)
       END AS newcol
FROM test;
```

But I am getting the following error with this code:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT)

The column "col" (varchar) is as follows

| col |
| --- |
| 7% |
| _ |
| 9 |
| 60% |

I want to have the following columns but as an int

| colInt |
| --- |
| 7 |
| Null |
| 9 |
| 60 |

Comment: I don't know any database that uses `CAST` like that, you should probably review the documentation. And it's a case *expression*

Comment: "but I am getting errors", when you ask a question about the errors you're getting, why don't you mention what errors you get?

Comment: This post probably needs some sample data to be answered. Not all your values may be integers.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I did mention they are syntax errors, pasted the full  message there for more info

Comment: Your query works well on most other dbms's; 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8735750b1c0cf687b645a489264176b Seems like MySQL has no INT data type.

Comment: ... at least when it comes to cast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you're looking for?

```
SELECT col,
       CASE WHEN REPLACE(col, '%', '') = '' 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST(REPLACE(col, '%', '') AS UNSIGNED)
       END AS newcol
FROM test;
```

You can also write it as follows:

```
SELECT col,
       CASE WHEN NOT REPLACE(col, '%', '') = '' 
            THEN CAST(REPLACE(col, '%', '') AS UNSIGNED)
       END AS newcol
FROM test;
```

More on numeric data types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

More on MySQL `CAST` function [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Comment: Good answer, and I understand you use the '' (defaulting to 0), but also explain this in your answer why this happens and how / if it could be avoided

Comment: Hi Lemon, thank you for your response. I'm still getting the same syntax error using the code you shared. The error says

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT)

Comment: This update should work in MySQL, given that all your non-empty values are integers.

Comment: Hi Lemon, just checked that and it seems to working, thank you! Just to be clear is the newly created newcol now an INT? Apologies, I'm very new to SQL and I'm not sure how to check

Comment: Yes, it is treated as an `UNSIGNED INT`. For more infos on numeric types, check the official documentation here >> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html.

Comment: Say 9 was -9 instead, what could OP do to handle signed integers?

Comment: He could change it to `SIGNED` in that case. The only *potential* drawback for using this solution is have the amount of addressable positive numbers halved (range is basically negatively shifted, to be centered on the 0).